# cant use laravel facase inside the package

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to write a package for laravel . i want to use `facade` and call some dynamic class with `::` like this :

```
Zaya::test();
```

so , my structure is `/packages/company/zaya` and here is my composer for package :

```
 "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Company\\Zaya\\ZayaServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {
                "Zaya": "Company\\Zaya\\ZayaFacade"
            }
        }
```

this is my fadace :

```
 protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'zaya';
    }
```

and this is my service provider :

```
     // Register the main class to use with the facade
        $this->app->singleton('zaya', function () {
            return new Zaya;
        });
```

and finally this is my class :

```
<?php

namespace company\Zaya;

class Zaya
{
    public function test()
    {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

now in my controller when i call :

```
        dd(Zaya::test());
```

i get this error :

```
    "message": "Non-static method Company\\Zaya\\Zaya::test() should not be called statically",
```

Comment: you are not referencing a Facade you are referencing the `Zaya` class directly it would seem

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `app` helper to resolve the class:

```php
class MyFacade
{
    public static function __callStatic($method, $arguments)
    {
        $class = app(MyClass::class);

        return $class->$method(...$arguments);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```php
MyFacade::foo();
MyFacade::bar();
MyFacade::baz();
// or in your case
Zaya::test();
```